# handle duplicate attribute in django model fields, looking for best practise

Tags: django, oop, django-models

I'm having a senario, where my model have different fields but the share the same attribute for example I have the following model:

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    pace = models.IntegerField()
    shooting = models.IntegerField()
    passing = models.IntegerField()
    dribbling = models.IntegerField()
    defending = models.IntegerField()
    physic = models.IntegerField()
    gk_diving = models.IntegerField()
    gk_handling = models.IntegerField()
    gk_kicking = models.IntegerField()
    gk_reflexes = models.IntegerField()
    gk_speed = models.IntegerField()
    .
    .
    .
```

**So Is there a way that can let me writing my model in better way?**

I mean when I want to update, for example, from `models.IntegerField()` to `models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(100),MinValueValidator(1)])`.
I have to do the update for the whole fields.

Comment: In pycharm highlight first one and press ` Alt + J / Shift + Alt + J `

Comment: code autocompletion tools might be what you are looking for, check the ones available for your editor

Comment: sorry @RezaHeydari what that command do? ... I tried to do it but nothing happened.

Comment: highlight a text and press alt + j, this works fine for me, 
this command let you edit with multi cursor

Comment: Aha @RezaHeydari, yea I see I was highlighting the whole line, this help, Thank you ... but I was looking for best practices to write my code.

Comment: @mrblu I will check that, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
class MyCustomIntegerField(models.IntegerField):
    default_validators = [MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)]
```

then use them on your models:

```
class Skills(models.Model):
    pace = MyCustomIntegerField()
    ...
```